# Is the space $\mathbb{N}$ is a baire spaces ? yes/No

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Is  the  space $\mathbb{N}$  is a  baire  spaces ?

My attempts :   No ,  It  will not form a  baires  spaces ,

let $C_n= \mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}$.
This is open (since $\{n\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, hence in the induced topology of $\mathbb{N}$) and dense, since every open ball with center in $\mathbb{n}$ intersects ${C_n}$. But 
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} {C}_n = \emptyset$$

So $\mathbb{N}$ is not a baires  spaces because for  Baire Space the intersection of a countable family of open dense sets must be dense.

Is  Its correct or not ?

Comment: $\{n\}$ actually is an open set (as well as closed) because $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, $\mathbb{N}$ is a Baire space, assuming $\mathbb{N}$ is equipped with the usual topology. The reason is the Baire Category theorem; $\mathbb{N}$ is a complete metric space (all Cauchy sequences are eventually constant!), and hence is a Baire space.

The reason your disproof doesn't work is because $C_n$ is not dense. In particular, $C_n \cap B(n, 1/2) = \emptyset$; there's no natural numbers other than $n$ within a distance of $1/2$ from $n$. That is, $n \notin \overline{C_n}$.